# Narcissistic number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Today I saw an interesting task. To make a program which outputs all "narcissistic numbers" (all digits are raised to the power of 3). My program has this code

```
for number in range(1, 408):
    result = 0
    for digit in str(number):
        result += int(digit) ** 3
        if result == number:
            print(number)
```

The output is

```
1
153
370
370
371
407
```

Why does 370 appear twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unindent the last `if` statement, which runs after each digit:

```
for number in range(1, 408):
    result = 0
    for digit in str(number):
        result += int(digit) ** 3
    if result == number:
        print(number)
```

As another answer notes, this can give you false duplicates if there is match in a number with trailing 0's. There is an added danger, though, of *false positives* if there is a number whose left X digits equal it, but whose total digits do not.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking whether `result==number` after each digit in the number. You probably want this check in the outer `for` loop. As it is, it sees that 370 = 3**3 + 7**3, but it is also 3**3 + 7**3 + 0**3, so it's printed on both of those iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will return true or false if number is narcissistic:

```
def narcissistic(number):
    number = str(number)
    empty_arr = []
    count = 0

    for n in number:
        n = int(n)
        empty_arr.append(n ** len(number))

    for n in empty_arr:
        count = count + n

    count = int(count)
    number = int(number)

    if count == number:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like that to solve the problem:

```
import math;
def narcissistic( n ):
DecimalPlaces = 0 if n == 0 else math.floor(1 + math.log10(n))
soma = 0
digit = 0
NarcissisticSum = 0
i = 0
for i in range(1,DecimalPlaces):
    digit = int((n % 10**i - digit) / (10**(i-1)))
    NarcissisticSum += digit ** (DecimalPlaces)
lastDigit = int((n - soma) / (10**i))
NarcissisticSum += lastDigit ** (DecimalPlaces)
return NarcissisticSum == n
```